# Crystal Reports: Change fill/background color of box in page header

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I have a mutli drill down report containing groups. One group is assessments and the data that displays is assessment date, KPI. KPI can be either a R, G, Y. What I'm trying to do is evaluate the last record of assessment date (last one submitted) and if the KPI is a R then change the fill/background color of a box in the page header to red, do the same if Y, yellow, G, green.

Do I create a formula and drop in it the section and do I use onlastrecord or var. An example would be great.

Thank you in advance.

I tried writing formula using onlastrecord but didn't get very far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a formula that concatenates the date and the KPI into a delimited string.
For example: ToText({assessment date}, 'yyyyMMdd') + "||" + {KPI}

In the conditional formatting expression, get the maximum value of the concatenated string, split it to an array (using the Split() function and the '||' delimiter), and grab the 2nd element in the array. That gives you the KPI in the last assessment date.

Comment: I'm trying to create the suggested formula in "new" formula. Is this the correct place. Also, can't get passed checking for error.

Comment: error is "too many arguments for this function" my code is totext ({Command.assessment_date},'yyyyMMdd') + "||" + {Command.kpi_indicator}

Comment: Probably, your {Command.assessment_date} is not a Date data type. If it's already a String data type, there is no need to convert it from date to text. Just make sure the value sorts correctly (latest date should be largest string value in the concatenated text.

Comment: Hey MilletSoftware-you were correct-date was already string and I could not figure it out with what you suggested (slowly learning CR syntext) but reading what you suggested triggered a different thought and I tried the following and it worked. The code was placed on the "box" background color.

Comment: if onlastrecord  then {Command.assessment_date};
if {Command.kpi_indicator} = "r" then crred
else if {Command.kpi_indicator} = "G" then crgreen
else if {Command.kpi_indicator} = "y" then cryellow